How to extend content view beneath the navigation bar in SwiftUI
In an iOS app, I wanted to place the content view under the navigation bar like in ZStack, so that the content view does not shift when the navigation bar hides / shows.
XCode: 15.3
iOS: 15 or 16
Currently I have this code:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ViewDismissApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyTabView()
        }
    }
}

struct MyTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                RandomView(title: "tab 1")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Tab 1")
            }

            NavigationView {
                RandomView(title: "tab 2")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Tab 2")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RandomView: View {
    let title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            ChildView()
        } label: {
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State private var showNavigationbar = true
    @State private var hideTabbar = true

    var body: some View {
        mainBody()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background{Color.green}
            .toolbar(hideTabbar ? .hidden : .visible, for: .tabBar)
            .onAppear {
                hideTabbar = true
            }
            .onDisappear {
                hideTabbar = false
            }
    }
    
    private func mainBody() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tap here to hide NavigationBar")
        }
        .onTapGesture(perform: {
            showNavigationbar.toggle()
        })
        .navigationBarHidden(!showNavigationbar)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .background{Color.yellow}
    }
}

The ChildView would visually move up and down when the navigation bar hides / shows.  Like in this screenshot:

When the user tapped the text, the navigation bar hides and the child view extends upwards and the text moves up as well:

How can I make the content view (in green) extends beneath the navigation bar in the first place (i.e. always) ?

Try changing the destination of the NavigationLink to Childview().ignoresSafeArea()

@BenzyNeez if I do that, the child view fills the whole screen. I didn't want that. I only want to go up under the navigation bar area.  (I still want to avoid the very top and the very bottom "curved edge" area)

The modifier .ignoresSafeArea can be used to get the main content to extend to the edges of the display.

Use edges: .top to ignore only the top safe area insets.

If the content should only extend up behind the navigation bar, use top padding to keep it away from the edge of the display.

A GeometryReader can be used to measure the safe area insets. The top padding can then be set to the size of the top safe area inset.

A GeometryReader aligns its content in the top-leading corner. So to keep the NavigationLink centered, set maxWidth and maxHeight to .infinity.


// RandomView

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        NavigationLink {
            ChildView()
                .padding(.top, proxy.safeAreaInsets.top)
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
        } label: {
            Text(title)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}



Thanks a lot! I'm curious about why this works: "So to keep the NavigationLink centered, set maxWidth and maxHeight to .infinity."

@user1783732 The default size of the link is just a small area, so if no frame is set, it appears in the top-left corner (because the GeometryReader aligns its content that way). By setting maxWidth and maxHeight to .infinity, the frame around the link is expanded to the full size of the display. The default alignment for the .frame modifier is .center, so the link appears centered. Hope that explains it, thanks for accepting the answer!
